# curl for windows fails

Tags: windows, powershell, curl

I execute a curl in unix which works fine. The same curl fails in windows.

**UNIX**

```
curl -k --user admin:f1f82c270ec3ce28b4279809900fa00b -H "Jenkins-Crumb:3e7dc5a087ef7697f4a31d74fb99c4ac" -X POST https://jenkins-xyz/buildWithParameters?token=test\&release_version=2.1.0
```

In windows powershell the same thing errors out with following

```
PS D:\Softwares\curl> curl.exe -k --user admin:f1f82c270ec3ce28b4279809900fa00b -H "Jenkins-Crumb:3e7dc5a087ef7697f4a31d
74fb99c4ac" -X POST https://jenkins-xyz/buildWithParameters?token=test\&release_version=2.1.0
At line:1 char:226
+ ... ers?token=test\&release_version=2.1.0
+                    ~
The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double
quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmpersandNotAllowed
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote your arguments or use the command operator (`&`) with PowerShell's command line.  It is interpreting your ampersand as the command operator.

```
& .\curl.exe -k --user admin:f1f82c270ec3ce28b4279809900fa00b -H "Jenkins-Crumb:3e7dc5a087ef7697f4a31d74fb99c4ac" -X POST https://jenkins-xyz/buildWithParameters?token=test\&release_version=2.1.0
```

[powershell-and-external-commands-done-right](http://edgylogic.com/blog/powershell-and-external-commands-done-right/)